# Cannot add filter in slickGrid React

Tags: slickgrid, slickgriduniversal

On adding  `enableFiltering: true`, throws an error

```
chunk-A7MMYRVG.js?v=6c5611bf:16659 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appendChild')
    at InputFilter.createDomFilterElement (slickgrid-react.js?v=6c5611bf:29900:30)
    at InputFilter.init (slickgrid-react.js?v=6c5611bf:29742:10)
    at FilterService.addFilterTemplateToHeaderRow (slickgrid-react.js?v=6c5611bf:26164:19)
    at SlickGrid.<anonymous> (slickgrid-react.js?v=6c5611bf:25475:12)
    at SlickEvent.notify (slickgrid-react.js?v=6c5611bf:9605:45)
    at SlickGrid.triggerEvent (slickgrid-react.js?v=6c5611bf:15844:16)
    at SlickGrid.createColumnHeaders (slickgrid-react.js?v=6c5611bf:14932:14)
    at SlickGrid.finishInitialization (slickgrid-react.js?v=6c5611bf:14231:12)
    at SlickGrid.init (slickgrid-react.js?v=6c5611bf:14024:10)
    at SlickgridReact.initialization (slickgrid-react.js?v=6c5611bf:41147:15)
```

Expected to see filter option below row header